# Validate at least one checkbox before submit on img submit

Tags: jquery

How can I validate the code below with 2 alerts?

The first check is that at least 1 checkbox is selected - if not, alert a message saying "Please select at least 1 checkbox!". The second should alert "Are you sure you want to delete?" and submit:

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

$("#delete").click(function() 
{   
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
                $('#form_test').submit();
    }
});

 });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a id="delete" href="#">Delete Images</a>

<form id="form_test" method='post' action=''>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#delete").click(function() {   
 var exists = $('input[type=checkbox][name^=remove]:checked').length;
    if( !exists ) {
         alert('Please select at least 1 checkbox!');
    } else if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
         $('#form_test').submit();
    }
});
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpwct/1/)***

---

### Note

New version of jQuery has deprecated the `:checkbox` selector. ***[List of deprecated items](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)***.

#### Reply to the comment of ***[@Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411945/validate-at-least-one-checkbox-before-submit-on-img-submit/12411969#comment16682124_12411969)***

From ***[jQuery doc about `:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)*** I found this:

> $(':checkbox') is equivalent to $('[type=checkbox]'). As with other
> pseudo-class selectors (those that begin with a ":").
>
> it is recommended
> to precede it with a tag name or some other selector; otherwise, the
> universal selector ("*") is implied.
>
> In other words, the bare
> $(':checkbox') is equivalent to $('*:checkbox'), so
> $('input:checkbox') should be used instead.

Comment: Why don't the jQuery devs don't just replace `:checkbox` with `[type=checkbox]` in the background in the selector string?

Comment: @Blender I've shared a link to doc about deprecation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$("#delete").click(function() {   
 var exists = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
     if( !exists ) {
         alert('Please Select any checkbox');
    } else {
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
         $('#form_test').submit();
       }
    }
});​
```

[Here is the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpwct/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `length` property.

```
$("#delete").click(function() {
    if (!$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
        alert('Please select at least 1 checkbox!')
    }   
    else if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
        $('#form').submit();
    }
});
```